# Visual Puzzle - Find the hidden message!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

See if you can figure this one out and find the hidden message!

[image]

There is more than 1 part!

Hint #1: 3=2=3

Hint #2:  | 166 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: been over a month, could we get another hint?

Comment: Color me "idiot." I can't even figure out what I'm supposed to do. I just see open and closed folders. Am I supposed to be using binary, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Profile.

Reasoning:

> Each row is an ASCII character, encoded in binary. Open=1, Closed=0

Comment: That's the first part, but there's more to it

Comment: @Paradox may want you to address the hints before accepting your response.  Also, welcome to Puzzling.SE.

Answer (score 4):

> Profile. Each row is an ASCII character in binary; closed folder == 0, open folder == 1

Comment: Congrats, you've finished part #1!  I've added hints for the rest of it.

Comment: figured there had to be more to it. onward!